# How to install Streamsets on aws?

Tags: streamsets

I am trying to install Streamsets on AWS.
What is an easy way to set up Streamsets on AWS ?
Is there any preferred AMI I can use or need to setup from scratch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already AMI available, but the installation is simple is and straightforward

the below link is steps for installing for RedHat / Amazon Linux and Centos Operating Systems

https://streamsets.com/blog/installing-streamsets-data-collector-amazon-web-services-ec2/